# String containment

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a way to check in Ruby whether the string `"1:/2"` is contained within a larger string `str`, beside iterating over all positions of `str`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-include-3F) method

```
str = "wdadwada1:/2wwedaw"
# => "wdadwada1:/2wwedaw"
str.include? "1:/2"
# => true
```

Comment: That's the `include?` method, the `?` is part of the name.

Comment: However, this solution, like every other solution presented here, will still iterate over all characters of the string. And there really is no way to avoid that: how do you know whether the string contains that substring without looking at the entire string? If you want to avoid iterating over the entire string, you need to use a different data structure. But if course, in order to build *that* data structure, you have to iterate over the entire string as well.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that is true. However, I'm pretty sure the OP simply meant to find a way to avoid explicitly iterating over the characters.

Answer (score 5):

A regular expression will do that.

```
s =~ /1:\/2/
```

This will return either nil if s does not contain the string, or the integer position if it does.  Since nil is *falsy* and an integer is *truthy*, you can use this expression in an `if` statement:

```
if s =~ /1:\/2/
  ...
end
```

The regular expression is normally delimited by `/`, which is why the slash within the regular expression is escaped as `\/`

It is possible to use a different delimiter to avoid having to escape the `/`:

```
s =~ %r"1:/2"
```

You could use other characters than `"` with this syntax, if you want.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest and most straight-forward is to simply ask the string if it contains the sub-string:

```
"...the string 1:/2 is contained..."['1:/2']   
# => "1:/2"
!!"...the string 1:/2 is contained..."['1:/2'] 
# => true
```

[The documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) has the full scoop; Look at the last two examples.

Comment: It's just spooky how many ways to do anything there are in Ruby. I didn't think of this one.